# conda : Имя "conda" не распознано Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda, pytorch

Есть установленная `Anaconda`, пытаюсь запустить файл `.py` в Visual Studio Code, предварительно установив интерпретатор Анаконды, но получаю следующую ошибку

```
conda : Имя "conda" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие 
и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ conda
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Скрин прилагаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело в том что conda не определяется как команда cmd или ps. Если нужно указать виртуальное окружение нажмите на `python 3.8.3 (conda)` и укажите путь к python.exe в этом окружении. (Поидее у Вас уже выбрано окружение конды)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня такая же ситуация была.
Я так понял это из-за того, что при установке Anaconda не был выбран "Add Anaconda to my PATH"
Т.е. мы должны пользоваться встроенным терминалом anaconda
Я решил проблему добавлением терминала анаконды в vs code:

Информацию нашел вот [тут](http://mscodingblog.blogspot.com/2017/08/setup-integrated-terminal-in-vs-code-to.html)
Но vs выдал предупреждение:

> This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default
> shell is by creating a terminal profile in
> `#terminal.integrated.profiles.windows#` and setting its profile name
> as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows#`. This
> will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that
> will change in the future.(2)

Собственно, как написано - то и делаем:
Settings > в поиск вбиваем terminal.integrated.profiles.windows и добавляем наш терминал (args смотрим в свойствах ярлыка Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3))

```
"Anaconda": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [
            "/K",
            "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3"
        ]
    }
```

Далее:
Settings > terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows
выбираем наш терминал